# How to estimate how much cpu and memory we need for a SQL Server machine?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

We have a SQL Server machine with 8 vCPU and 32gb of ram. Looking in monitoring tool, the average consume of CPU is only 1% last and current month. The customer wants to reduce the amount of vCPU and memory. How can we check the needed cpu and memory for this SQL Server? is there some metric inside SQL Server that suggest the amount of CPU and memory for the current workload?

**Some facts:**

Server is virtualized. It has 8 vCPUs and 32gb of ram.
The CPU average is 1%.
For SQL Server, the memory dedicated is 24gb. But it seems consume about 12gb (looking at the service in Windows task manager).

It seems is over dimensioned, mainly the amount of vCPUs. We need to reduce, it but I am not sure how much to keep.

Comment: You wrote about average. But do you have spikes? It is a production server?

Comment: About virtualization: it is on prem with VMWare, Hyperv,ecc.. or in cloud?